# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC does not transfer to the admin page when logged in to the admin page

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, admin, c#-3.0

On the admin controller page.

It successfully logs into the admin page and does not transfer it to the admin page with a return redirect after logging in - what am I doing wrong?

```
public IActionResult Login ()
{
        var model = new IndexViewModel()
        {
            Site = db.Site.OrderBy(x => x.SiteId).First(),
        };

        return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]       
public IActionResult Login (Site postedData)
{
    if (postedData.Email != null && postedData.Password != null)
    {
        var AdminEmail = db.Site.First().Email;
        var AdminPassword = db.Site.First().Password;

        if (postedData.Email == AdminEmail && postedData.Password == AdminPassword)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, postedData.Email)
                };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "admin");

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
            TempData["Success"] = "login successful";

            return Redirect("/admin");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Danger"] = "email / password is wrong!";
            return Redirect("/admin/login");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Danger"] = "Email / password cannot be empty";
        return Redirect("/admin/login");
    }
}

[Authorize]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel()
        {
            Site = db.Site.OrderBy(x => x.SiteId).First(),
            Slides = db.Slide.OrderBy(x => x.RowNumber).Where(x => x.IsConfirm == true).ToList(),
            Bands = db.Band.OrderBy(x => x.RowNumber).Where(x => x.IsConfirm == true).ToList()
        };

    return View(model);
}
```

It writes to the screen with tempdata that the login process is successful, but it does not transfer with redirect, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not awaiting the call to `HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);` - that might be why, or that might be an unrelated bug in your code. You need to make your POST Login method async and await it before redirecting.

Comment: Also, it looks like you aren't hashing the passwords in your database, which is another problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: how should I do You need to make your POST Input method async

Comment: Yes, you need to make your action method async.